# Can I use multiple servers to increase mysql's data upload performance?

Tags: mysql, database

I am in the process of setting up a mysql server to store some data but realized(after reading a bit this weekend) I might have a problem uploading the data in time.

I basically have multiple servers generating daily data and then sending it to a shared queue to process/analyze.  The data is about 5 billion rows(although its very small data, an ID number in a column and a dictionary of ints in another).  Most of the performance reports I have seen have shown insert speeds of 60 to 100k/second which would take over 10 hours. We need the data in very quickly so we can work on it that day and then we may discard it(or achieve the table to S3 or something).

What can I do? I have 8 servers at my disposal(in addition to the database server), can I somehow use them to make the uploads faster?  At first I was thinking of using them to push data to the server at the same time but I'm also thinking maybe I can load the data onto each of them and then somehow try to merge all the separated data into one server?

I was going to use mysql with innodb(I can use any other settings it helps) but its not finalized so if mysql doesn't work is there something else that will(I have used hbase before but was looking for a mysql solution first in case I have problems seems more widely used and easier to get help)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. That is a lot of data you're loading. It's probably worth quite a bit of design thought to get this right.

Multiple mySQL server instances won't help with loading speed. What will make a difference is fast processor chips and very fast disk IO subsystems on your mySQL server.  If you can use a 64-bit processor and provision it with a LOT of RAM, you may be able to use a MEMORY access method for your big table, which will be very fast indeed.  (But if that will work for you, a gigantic Java HashMap may work even better.)

Ask yourself: Why do you need to stash this info in a SQL-queryable table? How will you use your data once you've loaded it? Will you run lots of queries that retrieve single rows or just a few rows of your billions?  Or will you run aggregate queries (e.g. `SUM(something) ... GROUP BY something_else`) that grind through large fractions of the table?

Will you have to access the data while it is incompletely loaded? Or can you load up a whole batch of data before the first access?

If **all** your queries need to grind the whole table, then don't use any indexes. Otherwise do.  But don't throw in any indexes you don't need.  They are going to cost you load performance, big time.

Consider using myISAM rather than InnoDB for this table; myISAM's lack of transaction semantics makes it faster to load. myISAM will do fine at handling either aggregate queries or few-row queries.

You probably want to have a separate table for each day's data, so you can "get rid" of yesterday's data by either renaming the table or simply accessing a new table.

You should consider using the LOAD DATA INFILE command.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

This command causes the mySQL server to read a file from the **mySQL server's file system** and bulk-load it directly into a table.  It's way faster than doing INSERT commands from a client program on another machine.  But it's also tricker to set up in production: your shared queue needs access to the mySQL server's file system to write the data files for loading.

You should consider disabling indexing, then loading the whole table, then re-enabling indexing, but only if you don't need to query partially loaded tables.